# Php sort multidimensional/multiple arrays

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have three arrays that I want to print out with a nice sorting.

```
$person[]->name ('Foo','Bar','Foooo')
$person[]->sold ('10000','123123','234234')
$person[]->comment ('asd','qwer','zxcv')
```

Now I print out every array like this:

```
$total = 3;
$x = 0;
while($x<$total)
{
echo $person[$x]->name;
echo $person[$x]->sold;
echo $person[$x]->comment;
$x++;
}
```

This returns the content of the arrays. Actually I print out this in a table, but that doesn't make any difference.

**My question is if it's possible to print out the arrays and order by $person->sold for example?** 
If yes - how?

Many thanks!

Comment: The Answer you need is allready given in:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7814420/php-sort-multi-dimensional-array-by-another-array

Comment: I would start by grouping them together by person rather then by type: `$arrperson = get_object_vars($person); array_unshift($arrperson, NULL); $easierperson = call_user_func_array('array_map',$arrperson);` Then it's just an usort.