# Sort multidimensional array according to sub index

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have an array items following.

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2
            [field_id] => 2
            [1] => Photometric Interpretation
            [title] => Photometric Interpretation
            [2] => text
            [field_type] => text
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 3
            [field_id] => 3
            [1] => Make
            [title] => Make
            [2] => text
            [field_type] => text
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 4
            [field_id] => 4
            [1] => Model
            [title] => Model
            [2] => text
            [field_type] => text
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => 5
            [field_id] => 5
            [1] => Strip Offsets
            [title] => Strip Offsets
            [2] => text
            [field_type] => text
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [0] => 6
            [field_id] => 6
            [1] => Samples Per Pixel
            [title] => Samples Per Pixel
            [2] => text
            [field_type] => text
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [0] => 7
            [field_id] => 7
            [1] => Rows Per Strip
            [title] => Rows Per Strip
            [2] => text
            [field_type] => text
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [0] => 8
            [field_id] => 8
            [1] => Software
            [title] => Software
            [2] => text
            [field_type] => text
        )

    [7] => Array
        (
            [0] => 9
            [field_id] => 9
            [1] => Exposure Time
            [title] => Exposure Time
            [2] => text
            [field_type] => text
        )
)
```

I need to sort above array's `field_id` INDEX according to this following array's VALUE

```
Array
(
    [0] => 7
    [1] => 3
    [2] => 4
    [3] => 5
    [4] => 2
    [5] => 6
)
```

OR to following string

```
7,3,4,5,2,6
```

I have tried to sort array using `uksort()` and `uasort()`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP - Sort multi-dimensional array by another array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7814420/php-sort-multi-dimensional-array-by-another-array) - With 3.3k rep one should think you'd know to show us what you have tried.

Comment: @Epodax I already tried that link but does not work so I open new question.

Comment: [Do I really need to link this?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) - Show us what you have tried, why it didn't work, what errors you got and so on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usual foreach makes the desired result

```
$index = array_flip([7,3,4,5,2,6]);
foreach($arr as $item) 
   $res[$index[$item['field_id']]] = $item;
```

Comment: Thank you. You answer help me to fix the issue. I just addition of `ksort()` to you answer and got desired result :)

Comment: Glad that could help